# UPDATE en SQL con PHP

Tags: php, sql

Estoy verificando mis archivos PHP, los cuales reciben variables, para realizar la actualización que corresponda en la BD. Pero me encontré con el problema, en cada de ser incorrecto.

Es decir, mi código actualiza la PSW en la base de datos y lo informa con Sweetalert.

Pero si hay error, me sigue mostrando el alerta de edición correcta, pero la carga en la bd no se hace.

**CÓDIGO QUE ACTUALIZA EN BD Y MUESTRA SWEETALERT DE CONFIRMACIÓN:**

```
<?php

include("../conexsesion/conexion.php");

$usuarioid=$_POST['usuario_id'];
$usuario_psw=$_POST['txt_psw'];

$sql="UPDATE usuarios SET psw='$usuario_psw' WHERE id_usuario='$usuarioid'";

if (mysqli_query($acceso,$sql)) {
    setcookie("user_psw_1", 11, time()+3);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
} else {
    setcookie("user_psw_2", 22, time()+3);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
}    

?>
```

**CÓDIGO QUE NO ACTUALIZA EN BD PERO MUESTRA SWEETALERT DE CONFIRMACIÓN (DEBERÍA SER DE ERROR):**

```
<?php

include("../conexsesion/conexion.php");

$usuarioid=$_POST['usuario_id'];
$usuario_psw=$_POST['txt_psw'];

$sql="UPDATE usuarios SET psw='$usuario_psw' WHERE id_usuario='$usua'";   // CAMBIE LA VARIABLE PARA QUE ME DE ERROR, PERO NO...

if (mysqli_query($acceso,$sql)) {
    setcookie("user_psw_1", 11, time()+3);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
} else {
    setcookie("user_psw_2", 22, time()+3);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
}    

?>
```

**CÓDIGO QUE ACTUALIZA EN BD Y MUESTRA SWEETALERT DE ERROR (DEBERÍA SER DE CONFIRMACIÓN):**

```
<?php

include("../conexsesion/conexion.php");

$usuarioid=$_POST['usuario_id'];
$usuario_psw=$_POST['txt_psw'];

$sql="UPDATE usuarios SET psw='$usuario_psw' WHERE id_usuario='$usuarioid'";
$consulta=mysqli_query($acceso,$sql);
$existe=mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta);

if ($existe==1) {
    setcookie("user_psw_1", 11, time()+3);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
} else {
    setcookie("user_psw_2", 22, time()+3);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
}    

?>
```

**CÓDIGO QUE NO ACTUALIZA EN BD Y MUESTRA SWEETALERT DE ERROR:**

```
<?php

include("../conexsesion/conexion.php");

$usuarioid=$_POST['usuario_id'];
$usuario_psw=$_POST['txt_psw'];

$sql="UPDATE usuarios SET psw='$usuario_psw' WHERE id_usuario='$usuar'";
$consulta=mysqli_query($acceso,$sql);
$existe=mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta);

if ($existe==1) {
    setcookie("user_psw_1", 11, time()+3);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
} else {
    setcookie("user_psw_2", 22, time()+3);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
}    

?>
```

**USUARIOS.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>        
</head>

<body>
            <table>

                <thead>
                </thead>

                <tbody>                        
                </tbody>

            </table>

    <?php
        if (isset($_COOKIE['user_psw_1'])) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
            'usuario_psw_ok();',
            '</script>';
        } 
        if (isset($_COOKIE['user_psw_2'])) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
            'usuario_psw_error();',
            '</script>';
        }
    ?>            
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dependiendo de la configuración de PHP, con el cambio de variable podrías obtener una advertencia de variable no definida, pero el script continúa ejecutándose y `mysqli_query()` devolverá verdadero, porque no hay error en la consulta. En todo caso, deberías verificar el total de [filas afectadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Comment: @Triby Sí... voy a publicar esa opción, porque la hice también, y me funcionaba de la misma manera, pero me daba el sweetalert de error en ese caso jaja

Comment: @Triby Ahi puse los códigos contando las filas y los resultados son los mismos, pero con alerta de error siempre.

Comment: Estás pasando un parámetro incorrecto a `mysqli_affected_rows()`, debería ser la conexión en vez de la consulta. Además, sobra la línea `$row=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta);` porque no estás leyendo, sino actualizando.

Comment: Cuando funcione, puedes publicar la solución como respuesta, con el código correcto y explicando lo que estabas haciendo mal.

Comment: @Triby No lo puedo lograr... los sweetalert no son los que corresponden...

Comment: Entonces edita la pregunta para agregar el código de `menu_usuarios.php`, específicamente donde muestras la alerta.

Comment: @Triby Listo, agregué el código donde aparece... debe ser algo tonto, pero no lo veo...

Comment: ¿Por qué usas cookies en vez de variables de sesión? Además, en todo caso, usar solo una cookie con valor 1 si los datos son correctos y valor cero si hubo error.

Comment: @Triby Lo logré!!! Después de tu ayuda de ayer, había escrito mal la palabra en Inglés! Sobre las variables y las cookies, éstas últimas me resultaban más fácil. Igual estoy aprendiendo de cada consejo... soy novato y tomo cada cosa que me dicen. La próxima trabajo en eso. GRACIAS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Con el siguiente código he logrado el objetivo, de mostrar Sweetalert en caso de que exista error al momento de actualizar en la base de datos o bien de confirmación si se actualiza correctamente:**

```
<?php

include("../conexsesion/conexion.php");

$usuarioid=$_POST['usuario_id'];
$usuario_psw=$_POST['usuario_psw'];

$sql="UPDATE usuarios SET psw='$usuarioid' WHERE id_usuario='$usuarioid'";
$consulta=mysqli_query($acceso,$sql);

if ((mysqli_affected_rows($acceso))>0) {
    setcookie("user_psw_1", 11, time()+1);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
} else {
    setcookie("user_psw_2", 22, time()+1);
    header("location:../head_menu/usuarios.php");
}  

?>
```